# When Writing Python in Powershell it Returns Nothing

Tags: python, django, windows, powershell, command-prompt

```
**PS C:\Users\Shaad> python**
Program 'Python' failed to run: No application is associated with the specified file for this operationAt line:1 char:1
+ python
+ ~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ python
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

I am Finding for Quick Help and Also Need to Know why My `python manage.py runserver` Command in `Django` is Not Working properly anywhere.
I think the only problem is `python command Not Working` Please help as SOON.

Comment: You need to specify the full path to python.exe, eg `c:\Python37\Python.exe` or so. If running `python` directly from cmd works, then check your PATH environement variable to find which path it looks into for Python.exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your python application isn't added to windows path. Firstly Add Python to the Windows Path and then try again.

Comment: Did any python command working in the shell, like "python --version" ?
if this command shows your python version then the paths is added otherwise you have to uninstall the python interpreter and install it again with check the add to path option.